# Variable interpolation in -D option

Tags: cmake

As a package manager for a Linux distribution, I want to install docs into a separate prefix. With CMake projects, the docs installation location is controlled by `CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR` from [`GNUInstallDirs` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/GNUInstallDirs.html). Unfortunately, unlike the other [directory variables](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html), this one contains the project name so I cannot just use `cmake "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR=$myDocPrefix/doc"`.

With GNU Make, I would run `make "DOCDIR=$myDocPrefix/doc/\$(PROJECT_NAME)"` and have Make interpolate it but the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake.1.html#options) of CMake’s `-D` option does not mention interpolation and I understand that CMake uses much more complex system of cache entries where interpolation might be problematic (especially if the referenced variable is not yet in cache).

I could pass tailor-made `CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR` to each CMake project but would be bothersome as I would have to do that in every package definition manually; being able to define `configureCmakeProject` function and have it take care of everything automatically would be better. When setting it manually, I would also want to make sure it matches the `PROJECT_NAME` of the respective CMake project – well, I could resign on that and just use `$packageName` from the package definition instead but keeping packages as close to upstream as possible is preferred.

Alternately, I could try to grep `CMakeLists.txt` for [`project` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/project.html) but that seems fragile and might still result in misalignments. I doubt it is possible to extract it using some CMake API since the project is not configured at the time and we actually need the value to configure the project.

Is there a way I can configure `CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR` to use custom prefix but still keep the project name set by the CMake project?